# Can I rearrange games on my PLAY screen?

Tags: ouya

So I've download a bunch of games. Some are better than others, or likely to be revisited more frequently depending on circumstances. Is there a way to organize the screen without deleting and redownloading last the games I want on the right (or off screen)?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to organize them yet, but I hope they add one soon.

Answer (score 5):

Currently the PLAY screen is automatically sorted by last usage, i.e. the games you played most recently are on the left, and the ones used the longest time ago on the right. I haven't found a way to change this ordering so far.